# R: List of files run in a for-loop through whole script

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a beginner in R and I'm currently trying to run a script (which worked for a single .csv file) for a list of .csv files. So far I managed to read in all files as a list and tried to use a for-loop to set each file (one after the other) as the file with which the script should work. But somehow it doesn't work. I appreciate any help. Thank you!
Following code with for-loop as an short example:

```
           # load files 
        setwd("mypath/folder") # Files are stored in folder and used as wd
        list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv",full.names = TRUE)
        length_lof <- length(list_of_files)
        counter = 0

        for(i in 1:length_lof) {
         df <- list_of_files[1+counter]
         name <- sub(pattern = "(.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1_output.csv", basename(df))
         counter = counter + 1
         write.csv2(df, name)
        }
```

Original script which is working for a single file and now I would like to work it for a list of files/ all files in a folder with a for-loop (or something similar):

```
       rm(list=ls())
        setwd("C:/filepath/folder")

    # load data & adjust to R
    filename <- file.choose()
    name <- sub(pattern = "(.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1_output.csv", basename(filename))
    myData <- read.csv2(filename, sep= ",", skip=40, header=T )
    df <- myData[ -c(7) ]
    # get all col as numeric
    df[, 2] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[, 2]))

   #..... more code

    # Save Selected Data to new Data Frame 
    slope<-data.frame(dist[BS:BB],load[BS:BB])
    slope$ID <- ID
    colnames(slope) <- c("disp", "load","ID") # Rename Columns

    #Data Save 
    write.csv2(slope, name)
```

Comment: Change the last line to `write.csv2(get(df), name)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?? You do not have the dataframes loaded. You just have the paths

Comment: @RonakShah using `get` here wont work. df is just a path to a file somewhere in the computer. It has not been read into R

Comment: @Onyambu I forgot to mention that the files are in a folder which is selected using a wd

Comment: @RonakShah I tried you idea but unfourtunately I get the error "object not found" - but there is no problem with reading in the data as a list

Comment: Why do you want to use `write.csv`? it seems your problem is renaming the files

Comment: @Onyambu it's not about renaming the files. The data are "manipulated" in various ways - it's only the last step to save them with a different name. I just didn't put the whole code in there because it would be far to much and as far as I can tell the problem is that the for-loop doen't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Karen Sta - 1. Where do you _get the error "object not found"_? 2. How are you _reading in the data as a list_?

Comment: @Armali 1. The error occours when running the for-loop with "write.csv(get(df),name)" 2. with "list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv",full.names = TRUE)"  the data are read as a list, right?

Comment: @RonakShah I'm trying to run a script (which is working for a single file) on a whole list of data/ for all files in a folder automatically

Comment: Which script? What is in it? Right now, you are just writing the file paths using `write.csv2`.

Comment: @RonakShah I added the complete script (working for one file) to the question

Comment: @Aeidail - No, _with "list_of_files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv",full.names = TRUE)" the data are read as a list_ is wrong, since only the file names are read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mistook the file name for the file data. Change

```
 df <- list_of_files[1+counter]
```

to

```
 filename <- list_of_files[1+counter]
```

followed by

```
 name <- sub(pattern = "(.*)\\..*$", replacement = "\\1_output.csv", basename(filename))
```

and the rest of your original working script, ending with

```
 counter = counter + 1
 write.csv2(slope, name)
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! Unfourtanetly when I run the script I get follwoing error: "Error in basename(df) : a character vector argument expected"

Comment: You forgot to change `basename(df)` back to the original `basename(filename)` as I wrote (maybe unclearly) above.